# SSIS and skipping the first worksheet from excel workbook

Tags: ssis

I am new to SSIS and the task that i need to accomplish is to load each worksheet from the excel workbook except the first one.

I managed to use the script task and the foreach container to loop through all the worksheets but i am stumped on how to skip the first worksheet any idea ?

I also tried to use the excellent LINQ to excel provider but there seems to be no nuget with SSDT to install this package and use it in a script task.

How do i load all excel worksheet 's except the first one using SSIS ?

Comment: I would suggest that you share your code.

Comment: if you post your code we would be able to tell you how and where to modify it to skip the first sheet.  without knowing that if you know the first sheets name you can set up an expression in conditional precedence to test for when name is not equal to it.  Or you can modify your script task that is probably getting the sheet names to exclude it.  Will need your package flow and code to know best solution

Comment: There is no order to tabs to consider which one is first. You can only eliminate by name or even partial name.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your loop, add a script task at the beginning of the flow.   In the script task, check the name of the current sheet and set a variable that indicates whether this is a sheet you want to skip or process.

Then in the precedence constraint from the script task, check the variable to see if you should continue with the process or do nothing and loop to the next sheet.